# Rails Admin CSS not loaded on initial dashboard visit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass, rails-admin, turbolinks

I setup Rails Admin for a Rails appp that I created. When I first visit the /admin page, the HTML is rendered but it appears as though the CSS isn't being fully loaded. Example: [image: Dashboard screenshot] However, if I click the refresh button, the CSS is reloaded and the dashboard looks fine. [image: Post Refresh Dashboard]I've looked in the server logs and there aren't any errors pertaining to the CSS or JS not not loading. Has anyone experienced this issue before?

Comment: If you check firebug/chrome developer is the css file being loaded into the browser?

Comment: On the initial load of the dashboard, no, the Rails Admin CSS and JS files aren't being loaded. It appears that it may have to do with the link_to I use in the navbar. Going to the Rails Admin URL directly seems to work fine but clicking the Admin link in the navbar doesn't seem to trigger the a call to get the rails_admin.css and .js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears this may have been an issue related to Turbolinks. I added data-method: "get" to the link in the bootstrap navbar and it appears to have resolved my issue.

```
%nav.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top{role: 'navigation'}
  .navbar-header
    = link_to 'Building Permits Reporting', root_path, class: 'navbar-brand'
    %ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
      - if user_signed_in?
        - if current_user.role == 'Administrator'
          %li= link_to 'Administration', rails_admin.dashboard_path, class: 'navbar-link', method: :get
      %li= logon_menu
```

Comment: This solved issue for me as well. Was also having an issue from going between my app and the Sidekiq dashboard ( as well as Turbolinks) - Initially thought answer would be solved with ' = link_to "Admin", rails_admin.dashboard_path, turbolinks: false ' but the method: :get did the trick - requests look the same in the request though. Not sure what method: :get does that re-triggers asset load of rails engines w/ turbo-links..

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem on Rails 4.2 and Rails Admin 0.7.  The above solution setting the data-method: "get" on the link_to call worked for me.

Another thing that worked for me was just to [take out Turbolinks](http://corlewsolutions.com/articles/article-9-remove-uninstall-delete-turbolinks-in-rails-4).  After reading this [article](https://plus.google.com/+YehudaKatz/posts/A65agXRynUn), I decided I didn't want it for my low concurrency site.